# SSRS MS Dynamic Fetch Query Limitation

Tags: xml, reporting-services, fetch, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

I am working on an SSRS Report that will retrieve records based on a fetch query. You can find my fetch xml query in the image below:

[Fetch XML Query Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hDmq.png)

The  fetch query in the image above has an error in the fetch tag and is not throwing any records, however if I set the count to 5000 and page to 1 it will retrieve 5000. Shown in the image below:

[Sample report image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q6HIE.png)

I tried playing around with page and count, however this is the maximum that I can retrieve. Using fetch xml builder in XRM toolbox I can retrieve almost 26,000 records but when I used the query on SSRS I could only retrieve a maximum of 5000 records.

Any information and assistance will be greatly appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: You need to look at the RDLC (HTML script) to determine what is wrong.  In the HTML you will see the SQL string of the query.  See if there is a limit on the number of records.  If there is then that is the issue.  Otherwise, the issue is do to the number of pages in the report.

Comment: Hi, just in case this is with regards to the Pages in the report. How will I fix it?

Comment: I don't know until I see what is wrong.